# Interactive instantiation of Enums and structs in Rust

Tags: struct, rust, enums, user-input

I know how to input strings from users, but I would like to input an enum:

```
enum DoneAction {
    AddPassword {
        entry: EntryInput,
        result: Option<String>,
    },
    RemovePassword {
        location: String,
        result: Option<String>,
    },
}

enum Action {
    AddPassword,
    RemovePassword,
    Quit,
}
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
Please choose an action:
1: Add password
2: Remove a password
```

The program should loop if the user does not input 1 or 2:

```
Please input 1 or 2
```

And then, if the user inputs 1, I want to input a simple String, but if they input 2, I need to input three strings.

The program would ask for the location, then the identifier and the password.

I could implement the logic myself for this enum, but I would like to write something that can be used with different enums / structs.

Is there a procedural macro that I could use for this purpose?
Otherwise, is there another idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Check out the clap crate

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.